# What does pagesize query parameter represent?

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Looking at the  [New navigation for Stack Overflow is in alpha testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256814/233367) I have enabled this option and I did a quick go through.

When I navigated to `popular` tab following URL is redirected with `pagesize` as `15` in its queryParameter.

https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=popular&page=1&pagesize=15

However the number of results is more than 15.  When I change the size to `30` and `50`, the page is getting refreshed however the results is more than the `pagesize`.  See the attached screenshot:

[image]

Similarly when I navigate from [`popular`](https://stackoverflow.com/?page=1&pageSize=15) to `new` the redirect url is https://stackoverflow.com/?page=1&pageSize=15.  But `new` tab has no pagination initially.

Comment: I experience the same issue in meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I misread. I'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed, will be out in the next deployment.